# What does it signify for a question author to press Approve on rejected edits?

Tags: support, review-queues, user-interface, approval

I have an in-box alert showing me a (not-very-helpful) edit to a question of mine, showing two reject votes. Ok, interesting.

But it has a button for me marked "Approve" - what does it mean if I do or don't press that?

There is no other option, and I imagine it doesn't matter (much, or maybe at all) what I do, but is seems to me the UI designer might mean that if I press "Approve", it means I approve of the disapproval, or it might mean that that I approve of the edit.

And since it only offers one "Approve" button, whatever that means, I wonder what the UI wants me to do if I actually wanted the opposite of whatever that means?

(Honestly confused and curious...)

Comment: Related: [User experience of overriding community's decision on suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296166/164356)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the edit was already rejected, but you (as the question author) can approve it if you really want to.

If you don't care for the edit, then close the page & leave it rejected.

#### See also: [User experience of overriding community's decision on suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296166/164356)